# Respect for the Torah vs Respect for your Parents

Tags: halacha, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

I recall seeing that Kibbud Hatorah takes precedence over Kibbud Av. Does it? If one's father openly denigrates the Torah is it acceptable to chastise him & if the comment is made in front of ppl can one respond on the spot, publicly?

Comment: “Even if your parents beat your or spit in your face you shouldn’t put them to shame”

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel that's spit in _your_ face, not at the Torah

Answer (score 6):

Even if Torah study is greater than father's honor ([SA YD 240:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.240.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)), one should nevertheless take care in correcting one's father. The Rambam writes ([MT Mamrim 6:11](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1181857/jewish/Mamrim-Chapter-6.htm))

> If he sees his father violate Torah law, he should not tell him:
>   'Father, you transgressed Torah law.' Instead, he should tell him:
>   'Father, is not such-and-such written in the Torah?', as if he is
>   asking him, rather than warning him.

This is even more true in front of other people (see e.g., [here](https://www.ou.org/torah/mitzvot/taryag/mitzvah240/)).

Comment: worth noting that this is a way of keeping both.